# Binding source parameter inference in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently upgrading a project from [ASP.NET WebAPI 5.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.2.6) (OWIN) to [ASP.NET Core 2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/2.1.1) (Kestrel).

Our project is a single page application and we communicate via WebAPI with the client. Therefore I wanted to annotate the controllers wit the new `ApiController` attribute.

Unfortunately it seems that the [binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference) isn't working as expected (at least for me). I assumed based on the docs, that complex types (e.g. my `LoginRequest`) are inferred as `[FromBody]`.

#### Code (Controller & Startup)

```
// AccountController.cs

[Route("/account"), ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("backendLogin"), AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResponse>> BackendLogin(LoginRequest lr)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false); // do some business logic
        return Ok(new LoginResponse {UserId = "123"});
    }

    // Models

    public class LoginRequest {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginResponse {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}

// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvcCore()
                    .AddJsonFormatters(settings => {
                        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                        settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
                        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    })
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => {
        // options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
        // options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
        // options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

#### Problem

Calling the controller from the client via Ajax call (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`) results in a 400 (bad request) response, with content `{"":["The input was not valid."]}`. On the server I get the following trace output:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor: Information: Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError'.`

If I change the `options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters` in `ConfigureServices` to true, it seems to work. This is strange, since this setting should disable the binding inference or have I misconceived something? Is this a bug in ASP.NET core or am I missing something?

Btw. it also works if I ommit the `ApiController` attribute, but I guess this is not the real solution to this problem.
Furthermore I would be happy if I don't need to change anything on the client side (adding headers, change content types, ...), because there are a lot of Ajax calls out there and I just want to upgrade the server side components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this question on the official ASP.NET Core MVC repo.

One of the members ([pranavkm](https://github.com/pranavkm)) came back with an [answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8116#issuecomment-406334908), which I will just quote here:

> ApiController is designed for REST-client specific scenarios and isn't designed towards browser based (form-urlencoded) requests. FromBody assumes JSON \ XML request bodies and it'll attempt to serialize it, which is not what you want with form url encoded content. Using a vanilla (non-ApiController) would be the way to go here.

So for now I will omit the `[ApiController]` attribute. 
In a later step I may change the client calls to use a JSON body, so I can readd the attribute.